# Building a button only with image in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, chakra-ui

I've spent two days trying to figure out how to create a button with image in React but so far not able to achieve something shown below.

Screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve -- Files and Folders there are clickable buttons:

[image: Files and Folders]

I'm willing to use MUI or even better if this can be done using plain react.
Appreciate if anyone can show me how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use This Code**

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Button variant="text" size="small" style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
      <img src="https://www.tenforums.com/geek/gars/images/2/types/thumb_14486407500Folder.png" width="100" alt="folder"/>
      <label>Pictures</label>
    </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar as well

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img
        src="https://www.tenforums.com/geek/gars/images/2/types/thumb_14486407500Folder.png"
        alt=""
        onClick={handleClick}
        id="secret_folder"
      />
    </div>
  );

  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "secret_folder") {
      console.log("you clicked");
    }
  }
}
```